# Putting data under specific header based on table value PHP

Tags: php, html

I'd like to display data under specific header based on value in the "status" table. For example, if "status" table value is "0" then it's under "New tickets" header. If it's "1", then under "current". Can someone help with this one?

```
    <th id="typeleft" colspan="11">New tickets: <span id="numt"><?=$last_item_table?></span></th>

        <?for ($i=1; $i<=$last_item_table ; $i++) {?>
   <tr class="typeNew">
        <?if($i<=$last_item_table){?>
          

        <td id="tid"><p class="rep"><span><a href="<?=$table[$i][11]?>" target="_blank">#<?=$table[$i][2]?></a></span></p></td>
        <td id="tclient"><p class="rep"><span><?=$table[$i][3]?></span></p></td>
        <td id="tassign"><p class="rep"><span><?=$table[$i][4]?></span></p></td>
        <td id="tauthor"><p class="rep"><span><?=$table[$i][5]?></span></p></td>
        <td id="tcompany"><p class="rep"><span><?=$table[$i][6]?></span></p></td>
        <td width="5%" id="tsubj"><p class="rep"><span><?=table[$i][7]?></span></p></td>
        <td id="tlastup"><p class="rep"><span><?=$table[$i][8]?></span></p></td>
        <td id="tqname"><p class="rep"><span><?=$table[$i][10]?></span></p></td>
        <td id="tlastrespown"><p class="rep"><span><?=$table[$i][9]?></span></p></td>
```

Comment: When fetching data from the database, order by status. Then, while you're iterating and building your table, if you detect the status change (current item has a different status than the previous one) add another header at that point.